# Make all RelativeLayout same size

Tags: android-layout

I have multiple `RelativeLayout` inside `LinearLayout`. Inside my `RelativeLayout` it has 2 `TextView`. The value inside the `TextView` changes for example the date today.

What I'm aiming to do is that regardless of how long the value of my `TextView` is, whoever has the higher height the rest of the `RelativeLayout`'s size will be the same as the higher height.

Here's my xml

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

               <RelativeLayout
               android:id="@+id/today"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_margin="5dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:background="@color/lightblue">

                <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/day"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                 android:drawablePadding="5dp"                       
                 android:drawableStart="@drawable/calendar"
                 android:padding="5dp"
                 android:textColor="@color/white"
                 android:textSize="16dp"
                 android:textStyle="bold" />

                 <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/monthyear"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_below="@id/day"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:padding="5dp"
                 android:textAllCaps="true"
                 android:textColor="@color/white"
                 android:textSize="12dp"
                 android:textStyle="bold" />
               </RelativeLayout>

               <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/outbox_rl"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/lightblue">

                  <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/no_of_outbox"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                   android:drawableStart="@drawable/outbox"
                   android:padding="5dp"
                   android:textColor="@color/white"
                   android:textSize="16dp"
                   android:textStyle="bold" />

                   <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/no_of_outbox"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/outbox"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
               </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Currently it looks like this

[image]

but I want Outbox box to be the same height as the Today box.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the height of both the **Today** and **Outbox** `RelativeLayout` to `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/today"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/lightblue">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/calendar"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/monthyear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/day"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/outbox_rl"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/lightblue">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/no_of_outbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/outbox"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/no_of_outbox"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/outbox"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Just make sure that the height of the parent layout is set to `wrap_content` which you already have done in your code. :)

**OUTPUT**

With longer today text

[image]

With longer outbox text

[image]

With both with same text length

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `android:layout_weight="1"` to `android:weightSum="3"` and add  `android:orientation="horizontal"` in `LinearLayout`  and fix the height of `RelativeLayout`

Comment: How will I fix the height of `RelativeLayout` ? do I need to change `wrap_content`?

Comment: android:layout_height="match_parent"